# Java WindowBuilder JMenu Item to close app on mouse click

Tags: java, user-interface, windowbuilder

I want make an `onMouseClick` menu item to close the application.
I have tried to add `System.exit(0);` but its not work.

This is my piece of code:

```
JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
mntmExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}); 
mnFile.add(mntmExit);
```

Comment: Note: Not quite a duplicate question, but the mechanisms in the answers also apply here,

Comment: didn't understand what they are suggested...can you please tell me what should I add?

Comment: You can/should `dispose` the `JFrame`.